# How do I import talib library on imac M1 which is already installed?

Tags: apple-m1, python-3.10, ta-lib

After installing talib library on my imac M1 while importing talib using import function facing the following error.

Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libta_lib.0.dylib
'/usr/lib/libta_lib.0.dylib' (no such file)

Can anyone help me please